# Changing font style in seaborn clustermaps

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am using the clustermap method in the seaborn library and I would like to have the axis labels printed in italics. I don't think that seaborn allows me to specify the font style, so my question is, is there some way to encode italic font style into the label string? I have tried this, `[r'$\it{'+i+'}$' for i in data.columns]`, but it does not work. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how the latex-style formatting could be applied to the iris example:

```py
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_theme(color_codes=True)
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
species = iris.pop("species")
g = sns.clustermap(iris)
g.ax_heatmap.set_xticklabels([r'$\it{' + ticklabel.get_text().replace('_', '\\ ') + '}$'
                              for ticklabel in g.ax_heatmap.get_xticklabels()])
plt.show()
```

[image: clustermap with labels using latex formatting]